# JS: Filter array of objects using second array of objects using ID

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have two object arrays:

```
let array1 = [{ id:'1232', name: 'foo'}, { id: '3442', name: 'moo'}, {id: '3144', name: 'coo'}]

let array2 = [{ id:'3442', value: 'some'}, { id:'5553', value: 'somevalue'}, {id: '3144', value: 'lala'}]
```

Using JS, how can I filter `array1` by `array2` so that the expected output could be:

```
let filtered = [{ id: '3442', name: 'moo'}, { id: '3144', name: 'coo'}]
```

Thanks so much for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

combine filter and some to achieve this

```js
let array1 = [{ id:'1232', name: 'foo'}, { id: '3442', name: 'moo'}, {id: '3144', name: 'coo'}]

let array2 = [{ id:'3442', value: 'some'}, { id:'5553', value: 'somevalue'}, {id: '3144', value: 'lala'}]

output=array1.filter(x=>array2.some(y=>y.id==x.id))

console.log(output)
```